# Creating devise users from a CSV file - Rails - PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, devise, pg

I have been given a CSV file that contains emails and passwords.

My task is to go through this CSV file and create users using the devise gem.

You will probably wonder why I hace been given peoples emails and passwords (I am as well), but I've been told not to worry about it.

My csv file looks like this:

```
Email,Password,Password_confirmation,,
email1@email.com ,password1,password1,,
email2@email.com ,password2,password2,,
email3@email.com ,password3,password3,,
```

I wrote the following code in my seeds.rb file:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("db/fixtures/users.csv", :col_sep => ",", :headers => true) do |row|
User.create(email: row['email'], password: row['password'], password_confirmation: row['password_confirmation'])
end
```

I run `rails db:seed` to create the users, but nothing happens, no error messaged either.

Any support would be welcomed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are recording the `password_confirmation` as this is a computer, and it doesn't make mistakes (copying the same text from one field to another) ... unless this is raw input data from a user, and you'll be checking that the password and confirmation match later ... it has the feeling of a "bad design"

Comment: Good point! Absolutly no need for it, i wil delete the field!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's a really bad idea to put that file with actual passwords under version control and to import it in seeds.rb. Would be much better to add a rake task for that purpose accepting csv file path as an argument and perform it once in a suitable environment.

About the code, the headers in CSV import are case sensitive, so it would work if you get the row value via `row['Email']`, `row['Password']` etc.
Also, make sure that filling in those fields are enough to save the user, there may be some other required fields in your particular model.